# reproducing Photoshop's marquee tool using HTML5 and the Canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want, for my game, recreate the "Marquee tool" behavior that Photoshop has. But I don't have a clue on how to do it using the canvas element. Do I need to copy the element to a buffer canvas? how do I clip a selection? how do I make a selection?

A qualitative description of the approach I should take would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no other libraries I'd use `drawImage()` with the canvas as a source and another canvas as a destination to snip out a subsection. See [the specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage) for how you can extract a subsection of the image.